# How use GSON when JSON doen't have "Name attribute"?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have the follow JSON (from URL)

```
["Rock","Rock Argentino","Reggaeton","En Español","Reggaeton ","Reggaeton  ","Boleros","Italianos ","Cumbias ","Cumbia ","Internacional","Internacional "]
```

You can see that there isn't a "name attribute"  for these fields.

My class model is the follow

```
public class KaraokeCategoryModel {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

but the GSON doesnt reconize my atribute "name"

```
Type karaokeCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<KaraokeCategoryModel>>() {}.getType();
        _karaoke_cartegory_response = new Gson().fromJson(reader, karaokeCollection);
```

later I create the adapter

```
_karaoke_category_adapter = new KaraokeCategoryAdapter(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, _karaoke_cartegory_response);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(_karaoke_category_adapter, this);
```

What should I do to make GSON used my model without problems?

Comment: Why not just read it as a `List<String>` and create a `KaraokeCategoryModel` object with each string? (You will need to create a constructor for your class.)

Comment: @ChthonicProject Is it complicate create adapter with that option??

Comment: I don't see how creating the adapter will change based on how you create the `KaraokeCategoryModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that more easier with code below:

```
List<KaraokeCategoryModel> karaokeCategoryList = new ArrayList<KaraokeCategoryModel>();

JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(yourJsonStringValueHere);
JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
Iterator iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    JsonElement jsonElementInArray = (JsonElement)iterator.next();

    KaraokeCategoryModel karaokeCategory = new KaraokeCategoryModel();
    karaokeCategory.setName(jsonElementInArray.getAsString());

    karaokeCategoryList.add(karaokeCategory);    
}
```

Comment: excelent help but the aplication crash in **JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(URL);** can I put the URL JSON there??

Comment: I don't think so. see how to get a json value(string) from a uri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966672/java-json-with-gson